# ¿Como hacer para que mi columna me permita valores nulos en un dataGridView? NetCore

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, asp.net-core

al intentar traer a mi dataGridView datos desde la BD, varios de estos estan en null, por lo cual al mostrarlo me arroja lo siguiente

> String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Cree una clase y coloque  `?` para que me permita valores nulo, pero no funciona

```
public DateTime? Fecha_inicio;
```

En el recorrido del `While` , he colocado mi codigo de esta manera para traer mis datos pero no funciona me sigue diciendo `String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

```
Fecha.Fecha_inicio = DateTime.Parse(reader[0].ToString(), null);
Fecha.Fecha_inicio = DateTime.ParseExact(reader[0].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
Fecha.Fecha_inicio = DateTime.ParseExact(reader[0].ToString());
```

De que manera puedo hacer que mi campo `Fecha_inicio` acepte valores null

Comment: Haz intentado poner el signo `?` en el string, de esta manera `DateTime.Parse(reader[0]?.ToString()`, igual intenta ponerselo al `DateTime?.Parse`

Comment: De esa manera ya lo habia intentado y el problema continua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola tienes que ver si el valor de la columna es nulo o tiene valor. Si es nulo poner Fecha_inicio en nulo y si tiene valor poner la fecha

```
Fecha.Fecha_inicio = reader[0] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(reader[0]), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

o si en lugar de nulo es un string vacío (todo depende de tu query)

```
Fecha.Fecha_inicio = string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader[0]) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(reader[0]), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono, solo que cambie la condicion ternaria del else por esto DateTime.Parse(reader[13].ToString()); de esa manera no cambio el formato traido de mi BD